# Using ADO.NET in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I am new to ASP.NET MVC, I did some research using classic ADO.Net in MVC, actually I didn't get repository things and I'm using that way... is it good practice to use this way ADO.net in ASP.NET MVC?

Business layer:

```
public static List<Employee> GetAllfromDB()
{
    string CS = "Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=test; Integrated Security=True";

    List<Employee> employee = new List<Employee>();

    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee",con);

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while(dr.Read())
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"].ToString());
            emp.Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            emp.Gender = dr["Gender"].ToString();
            emp.Salary = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Salary"].ToString());
            emp.DepartmentID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DepartmentID"].ToString());

            employee.Add(emp);
        }

        return employee;
    }
}
```

And controller like this:

```
List<Employee> fromdb = Repository.GetAllfromDB();

//foreach(var i in fromdb)
//{
//    Console.WriteLine("ID:{0} Name:{1} Gender:{2} Salary:{3} DepartmentID:{4} \n", i.id, i.Name, i.Gender, i.Salary, i.DepartmentID);
//}
```

Comment: I would argue it would be better to use something like **Entity Framework** to save yourself from having to write *a lot of low-level*, boring, error-prone SQL code......

Comment: Is *what* good practice, specifically? This is not a code review site, so I think your question should be a bit more specific.

Comment: Gosh! Clearly im asking is it fit MVC rules ! if its not code review web whould u mind show me usage this piece of code in REpository Part.

Comment: this is actually not MVC question. You use ADO for your DAL (Data access layer) as @marc_s mension it's just cleaner to use some sort of ORM for this application layer. But you certainly can use ADO. Moreover for som difficult sitiotions you have no other solution.

Comment: Thanks for answers, i have like 20 Table in Database and this tables has no foreign key btwenn em(this must be like that) when i using EntityFramework i have troubles to get data from this tables using Join lambda expression its ownt for like that tabl1().Join(table2) Entity want to foreign in this tables, that why im trying to use old school ADO